# htaccess redirect if multislashes at the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

because of SEO requirements I have to catch all these types of requests:

```
1 - http://example.com
2 - http://example.com////
3 - http://example.com////about
4 - http://example.com////about////
5 - http://example.com////about////info
6 - http://example.com////about////info////
```

and forward users with 301 redirect to

```
1 - http://example.com/
2 - http://example.com/
3 - http://example.com/about/
4 - http://example.com/about/
5 - http://example.com/about/info/
6 - http://example.com/about/info/
```

For the first case I use

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

But can't understant how to write rule for other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add trailing slash if missing
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# remove multiple slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)//(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Remove multiple slashes anywhere in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But why do you get URLs like this? Is any CMS out of control?

Comment: `////////about/info` remains unchanged with this